# How to autoscroll through a datarepeater display?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, datarepeater

In my webforms site in asp .net using c# in VS2015
This is a dashboard application, and 
I have a situation where i have datarepeaters which have a row count that do not vertically fit on a display.
What i would like to do is do a auto scrolling data repeater, where the repeater starts from record 1 and gradually scrolls down to last record. Once it hits the last record it should go to the top record and start again.
the marquee tag has been deprecated, and most of my attempts at using various jquery functions with the help of internet haven't really worked out.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to do it myself.
Used jquery ticker.